# Spring Batch java.sql.SQLException.RowMapper get number of page and record number

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-jdbc, rowmapper

How can I get the number of page in a java.sql.SQLException.RowMapper interface?

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

    public class MyRowMapper implements RowMapper<MyDto> {

        private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(MyRowMapper.class);

        public MyDto mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

            log.info(" Page: " + page + " Record " + rowNum);


           }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have information about number of page on a RowMapper interface. It just an interface to map resultset into Java object.